# Constant Scan doesn't work in MS SQL when I use variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I have a query that takes long time to complete and that I don't want to execute if some variable is false.

```
DECLARE @b = 0

SELECT *
FROM DummyTable
WHERE @b = 1
```

However, it still takes a lot of time to complete while I expect Constant Scan to be executed first:

[image]

My expectation is:

```
SELECT *
FROM DummyTable
WHERE 0 = 1
```

With execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Why not use an `IF` instead then?

Comment: @Larnu, it's inside inline function so I can't use T-SQL here.

Comment: You *are* using T-SQL here, @Chaika_va, however, no you can't use an `IF` in an inline table-value function (you've omitted that information in the above). What you might, however, consider doing is using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Does that change the plan?

Comment: @Larnu, yes, OPTION (RECOMPILE) changes the plan as expected. So if I put the option on the query that is using the function it helps. Thanks!

Comment: You won't get a `Constant Scan` as that is only relevant if the compiler can guarantee the rest of the query will not be run, but what you are looking for is a `Filter` with a `Startup` predicate. An option for forcing a `Startup` is `SELECT TOP (1000000000) * FROM DummyTable WHERE @b = 1`

Comment: Your example is incomplete to describe the rest of the query.  An arbitrary query may or may not be able to be rewritten to enable the optimizer to determine that there is a contradiction (which it then replaces the tree with a constant scan of zero rows).  You can use option (recompile), however, to inline literals for a given execution and for the cases where it can determine the contradiction, it will do the same transformation you are hoping to see.